# How to remove the ask for consents for azure app registrations?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, blazor-server-side, microsoft-identity-platform

I am building an application with the following setup:

- An azure AD app registration reg1 to protect web apis (.NET 7), I use MS Identity.Web
- An azure ADD app registration reg2 to protect a blazor server app which is the client app
- reg1 exposes 3 scopes
- reg2 has the permission to access the scopes and is among the authorized client applications

However, the client application always asks for consent and I am obliged to add a ConsentHandler in all the pages.

According to MS documentation, adding reg2 as an authorized app in reg1 should remove the need for asking users for consents but this is not the case.

How to disable asking for consents between these two apps?

Thanks in advance

[image]

I added reg2 to the authorized apps but this did not work

Answer (score 1):

Please try to do the following:

In Azure Portal > Azure AD > App Registrations and click on your API app (reg1) and then click on Manifest. Search for `knownClientApplications` there. Just add the Application (client) id of your frontend app (reg2) there. Something like:

```
"knownClientApplications": ["<reg2 client id>"],
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Updated the manifest but it is still not working and still asking for consent. Does it require time to have affect?

Comment: `Does it require time to have affect?` - I do not recall anything regarding this. In my application, I had set this setting to suppress the consent from the frontend app.